# arr.delete() vs arr.delete_at() in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I wrote the function below which accepts an array and returns a randomized version of it.

I've noticed that I sometimes end up with a nil element in randomizedArr when using list.delete(element) to remove an element from the array, but this does not happen when using list.delete_at(index) -- note that the latter is commented out in the below snippet.  Am I missing something?

If there's a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve with this function then I would appreciate any suggestion.  Thanks!

The array I'm passing to this function is a string array with ~2k elements. I'm passing in a clone of the original array so it doesn't become empty when the function is called.  I'm using Ruby 2.1 on Windows 7.

```
def getRandomList(list)
    randomizedArr = Array.new()
    cnt = list.length
    while (cnt >= 1) do
        index = rand(cnt)
        prod = list[index]
        randomizedArr.push(prod)
        list.delete(prod)
        #list.delete_at(index)
        cnt = cnt - 1
    end

    if randomizedArr.include?(nil)
       puts "found nil element"
    end

    return randomizedArr
end #getRandomList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the Ruby documentation, this is what I found to answer your question:

```rb
#To delete an element at a particular index:
arr = [2, 3, 4, 5] #I added this bit
arr.delete_at(2) #=> 4
arr #=> [2, 3, 5]

#To delete a particular element anywhere in an array, use delete:

arr = [1, 2, 2, 3]
arr.delete(2) #=> 2
arr #=> [1,3]
```

All of that can be found here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html

`arr.delete(2)` will remove any instance of 2 in an array while `delete_at(2)` only removes the third value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need to put all that logic when you can randomize the list by `list.shuffle`.

Comment: Also, as @archana says, you can make the same list `list.shuffle!` to mutate the instance of the list.

Comment: Hi @archana, I did all that logic because I didn't know about list.shuffle.  I'm really a newbie in Ruby.  Thanks!  Still, I would be curious to know why delete(element) was behaving differently in my usecase compared to delete_at(index) just for my education.  Could that be a bug, a race condition perhaps?

Comment: I ran your script on a smaller set and I don't get nil.

Comment: I've noticed this too, i.e. doesn't happen all the time especially on a small array.  But it happens more often than not on the string array I'm using with ~2k elements.  Thanks for the info on shuffle(), BTW.  I wanted to upvote your answer but I think it won't reflect right now since I just joined the forum. Cheers